# Beamer \date broken

Tags: beamer, date

I am creating a presentation with Beamer and I just noticed that the date on the title page is broken. Wherever I write `\date`, the result is:
[image]

It doesn't matter whether I compile it with Latex, XeLaTeX or LuaLaTex.
I am already using a variety of packages. This is a small working example:

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  mathescape
}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{changepage} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

My output is:
[image]

Comment: Don't show only a header but a small but complete example.  That makes it much easier to test solutions.

Comment: If I comment out `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` and compile the example code using `PDFLaTeX`, I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxUnM.png

Comment: If I then also comment out \usepackage[greek]{babel}} the date is shown correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are trying to create a Greek document.

So, the correct settings are:

`\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}`

and

`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: Is `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` really needed?  I suppose, that OP have no to old LaTeX installation, where this is default encoding. Or is `beamer` exception in this?

Comment: If I only modify these two commands, the hole title page is in Greek.

Comment: Try `\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}` if you want english to be your basic language (also, use `\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}` )